# Remotely performing tasks on a remote Windows Server 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-access, automation

I have to perform various tasks such as restarting processes, monitoring the state of processes, checking disk space and log monitoring on Windows Server 2003.

In order to do this, I am currently using remote desktop which is very slow.

Are there any tools or frameworks for Windows Server 2003 using which I can execute the script on my machine and the required task will be performed on the remote machine in a somewhat interactive manner (like putty in linux)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this. My preferred method is to use [`psexec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553).

Comment: +1 for PSexec.  Either Powershell or PSexec can be used to "execute a script... and the required task will be performed on the remote machine..."  But neither one is truly analagous to telnet/ssh in the unix world.  To fully administer a Windows box, you need the gui sooner or later.

Comment: Indeed PsExec is a grat tool. We can get the command prompt instance of remote machine by "psexec -u userid -p password cmd.exe". Thanks a lot for ur reply

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [`wmic`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) or install [PowerShell](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968930) (preferred). Neither of these (nor `psexec`) are really interactive, though. What do you need this to be interactive for?

Comment: By interactive i just mean i should be able to see progress of my task on remote machine, if the task fail than fail log should be displayed, if any batch file is executed should be able to enter input to it.

Comment: You can't enter input with `PsExec`, although it will return the output. When using `wmic` the script will run locally and `wmic` will connect to the remote host, so your script can prompt for input. With PowerShell it depends.